# Cake php Post request Error: The requested address was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp

When I try to post a post request to my function I end up with the above area.

My controller:

```
public function app_new($profile_type) {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        // The default response
        $response = array('status' => 'FAIL', 'message' => 'There was a problem.');

        // Check the request is POST
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            // Get the current logged in users id
            $sesh = $this->Auth->user();
            $user_id = (isset($sesh['User']['id'])) ? $sesh['User']['id'] : null;

            $response['status'] = 'OK';
            $response['message'] = 'New post created successfully.';

        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

When I try to fire a post request to the url I get the error, however if I do a get request I get the default response json as I should.

So when I make a post request with the url "http://localhost/app/messages/new/1" I get the error but a get request to the same url gives the right response

Comment: remove `$profile_type` from function and check. and also whn you call this function check that in url no value will append. thanks.

Comment: if you are having a form then method must be post.

Comment: Still get the same, this `$profile_type` will also have a roll to play in my code later.

Comment: then send it also through POST method.

Comment: also comment `$this->autoRender = false;` this line and check.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why you use `$this->autoRender = false;` is because you are sending an ajax request.

And if it's ajax, it's best you check

```
if($this->request->is('ajax')){

//Do your coding here
}
```

Also I did not see where you save your data, but you just return `json_encode`, and note that `json_encode` should be return inside 
the `if($this->request->is('ajax'))` block.

One last thing but not the least, you need also to have:

```
Router::connect('/app_new', array('controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'app_new'));
```

Even though the function is not rendering any view the route has to be there.